# Reqex to match between backslashes

Tags: regex, unc

I'm looking for help with a regex. I have the following UNC path `\\server\share1\folder1` that I would like to grab `server` from. The server name will always be different and sometimes be an IP address.

I have the following Expression that I have been working with but I can't seem to get it to work the way I want.

```
\\?.*\\
```

This returns the following result `\\server\share\`.  Can someone help me just grab `server` and not `\\server\`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
^\\\\.*?\\
```

`^` is a beginning of line anchor and will match only at the beginning.

`.*?` is a modified version of `.*` so that it will match up to the match of the pattern following it; usually called to be matching 'as little as possible', in opposition to its 'greedy' counterpart.

---

Alternatively, you can use a negated class:

```
^\\\\[^\\]+\\
```

`[^\\]+` matches any character except backslashes.

---

And if you want to get `server` without the backslashes, you should be able to use a capture group (by using parentheses) and extract the matched group (through `$1` or `\1`):

```
^\\\\(.*?)\\
```

or

```
^\\\\([^\\]+)\\
```

Or if UNC finds any first match by default, then you can simply use `[^\\]+`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and help. I was able to get the value I wanted using "[^\\]+"

Comment: @Mpit52 Oh, yep, that usually works depending on the function you use, but if UNC's way to deal with regex accepts this, cool! :)

Comment: @Jerry: A UNC path starts with *two* backslashes, but we weren't seeing them because the OP didn't use code formatting.  That means the long form of your regex should have been ``^\\\\([^\\]+)\\``.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing string.split (or its equivalent in the language you're using) with '\', then get "server" from the resulting array

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?<=^\\)[^\\]+(?=\\)
```

This would match `server` in `\server\share\folder`.